# What kind of loop or function can be used to simplify this code?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, function, indexing

Is there a loop or function that I can use in Python to simplify down this code, so that I can go through an entire list and return the result of each iteration? I need to apply the value of the row index to iloc and as a function parameter.

I've tried while loops, but I get `<function __main__.()>` in return when I put it in a function.

```
IndexList = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...,99]

IndexPosition = 0
row_index = IndexList.index[IndexPosition]
Result = dfColumn1.iloc[row_index] / dfFunction(row_index) 
Result 
#Output

IndexPosition = 1
row_index = IndexList.index[IndexPosition]
Result = dfColumn1.iloc[row_index] / dfFunction(row_index) 
Result 
#Output

IndexPosition = 2
row_index = IndexList.index[IndexPosition]
Result = dfColumn1.iloc[row_index] / dfFunction(row_index) 
Result 
#Output

etc
```

Ideally, I'd like it so the output is:

```
#Output of function from Index Position 1
#Output of function from Index Position 2
#Output of function from Index Position 3
#Output of function from Index Position 4
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense, your list doesn't look like it contains Indexes 1 and 2.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The IndexPosition is a variable I'd like to step += 1 in some kind of loop. So, that it repeats the chunk of code and returns the Result for each time its executed

Comment: But your IndexList doesn't seem to contain 1, 2, 3... etc. So `IndexList.index(1)` will raise an error.

Comment: Okay, I've edited it so the list now contains the integers. Will this help make the loop easier?

Comment: Are they supposed to be continuous numbers from 0 to 99? If so, why not use `range(100)` instead?

Comment: I think I'm seeing my issue now. For some reason I thought that the number inside .index() found whatever value was at that index position, not that it finds the index position of that number

Comment: Yes, if you want a value at specific index you should use `[x]` instead. (Like this: `IndexList[1]`)

Comment: My actual list is almost 10,000 digits long all in steps of 1. I'm just simplifying it down to 99

Comment: I hope you didn't define it manually though?

Comment: No, no. I actually turned a column of my dataframe into a list, as I thought it'd be easier to do a loop that way. My original function takes a value from within a column of my dataframe and returns an associated value. But I want to find the associated value for every cell in that column, if that makes sense

Comment: Check my edited answer, it will not solve your problem directly, but it might help you get on the right track.

Comment: Thanks. I think I now have an error in my function, because I got "Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key"

Comment: Hard to debug without knowing your actual code and data.

Comment: Would you be willing to look at it in a chat? I've been staring at this code for two days trying to get it to iterate through the column

Comment: Yeah, I'll look at that in free time.

Comment: I don't think it'll let me; I don't have enough reputation. That's fine, I'll just keep playing around with it

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a few steps back from the columns and indexes you extracted. Pandas dataframes offer a lot of direct ways to iterate over the columns or cells themselves.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': {0: 1, 1: 200, 2: 4, 3: 5, 4: 6}, 
                     'y': {0: 4, 1: 5, 2: 10, 3: 24, 4: 4},
                     'z': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}
              })
results = []
for idx, x in enumerate(df.iloc[:, 1]):
    results.append(df.iloc[idx] / dfFunction(x))

for res in results:
    print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a for(each) loop with index using the built-in function enumerate():

```
for value, index in enumerate(IndexList):
    print(value, index)
```